# Power bi Load multiple-language reports

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a report using multiple language labels to load in a web page based on a specific language code. For the moment I created a blank web page that loads a report with a publish to web link and I wanted to specifie the language in the link or in the code. Is this possible without using Power BI embedded?
I saw this in a microsoft post but even with the localized labels or the field parameters I can t make this work in my code. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/data-translation-load-report-bookmark)

My code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PowerBIReport from './components/PowerBIReport';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Power BI Report Demo</h1>
      <PowerBIReport />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PowerBIReport.js:

```
// src/components/PowerBIReport.js
import React from 'react';

const PowerBIReport = () => {
  return (
    <iframe
      title="PowerBIReport"
      width="100%"
      height="800"
      src="ReportURL"
      frameBorder="0"
      allowFullScreen="true"
    ></iframe>
  );
};

export default PowerBIReport;
```

This is to test for in the future I could use it in a portal and load the report based on the user language code that we is currently using in the portal, we can have the computer in fr-FR but using the portal in en-US and with this the report would be loaded in en-US and not fr-FR from the USERCULTURE()